# rails append url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've seen some posts that talk about appending URLs but I haven't really found anything that will help me in my views. I have some links that I would like to append the current URL to add additional parameters.

Is there a standard practice for this in rails?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_params = {
    'a' => 'test'
}
url_for(my_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `url_for(:a => 'test')` or for example `users_path(:a => 'test')`.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of ways to do this.

```
params = "?a=test"
url = request.full_path << params
```